# How to custom style of lable in react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

how to custom this lable, i want style print straight and display less[image]

I tried changing some options plugin:

```
 <Chart
      type="line"
      data={data}
      options={{
        plugins: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            align: "center",
            color:"red"
          },              
        }
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scales: {
x: {
display: true,
maxRotation: 0,
},
},
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).